# how to hide the layout in android

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera

am working on android camera application but in my application time clock is showing time i didn't know how is implement .i want to stop these time how can i remove this time title .please assist me

[image]

```
enter code here
   protected void onCreate(Bundle bd) {
    if (MyDebug.LOG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
    long time_s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.onCreate(bd);
    this.preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

}

Comment: where is full code dear ?

Comment: actualy i am no define and declare time property i did not know how is it showen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think where you declare the time function at that time you show this
you can use

```
enter code here

time.setenable(false);
```

Comment: thanks dear let me check .